# Correct way of using REST DELETE?

Tags: rest

I am trying to delete some items connected to a product. Like this:

```
DELETE /products/Special product/11
```

So item 11 in "Special product" will be deleted? Is this a correct way of using the `DELETE` verb? I should probably url encode `Special product` right?

Special product is *not* stored in a DB. So I can't use some id. I have to write it out like this (alpha+digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
/products/Special prodcut
```

is the collection resource of *all* "special products", and if

```
/products/Special product/11
```

is the "special product" resource with ID 11, then your usage of `DELETE` is RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you have a collection of products

```
/products
```

You are selecting the "special product" (its some kind of an identifier?)

```
/products/special product/
```

This one product contains multiple "items"? And you want to delete the item connected to "special product" with the id=11? If this is the case, the uri should look more like

```
DELETE /products/special product/items/11
```

As Example, you have albums with images. To get all albums:

```
GET /albums
```

To get one album

```
GET /albums/{albumId}
```

To get all images for one album

```
GET /albums/{albumId}/images
```

To delete/remove one image from one/this album

```
DELETE /albums/{albumId}/images/{imageId}
```